# readcsv fails to read # character in Julia

Tags: julia

I've been using `asd=readcsv(filename)` to read a csv file in *Julia*.

The first row of the csv file contains strings which describe the column contents; the rest of the data is a mix of integers and floats. `readcsv` reads the numbers just fine, but **only reads the first 4+1/2 string entries**.

After that, it renders "". If I ask the *REPL* to `display asd[1,:]`, it tells me it is `1x65 Array{Any,2}`.

The fifth column in the first row of the csv file (this seems to be the entry it chokes on) is `APP #1 bias voltage [V]`; but `asd[1,5]` is just `APP` . So it looks to me as though readcsv has choked on the "#" character.

I tried using "quotes=false" keyword in readcsv, but it didn't help.

I used to use *xlsread* in Matlab and it worked fine. 
Has anybody out there seen this sort of thing before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment character in Julia is `#`, and this applies when reading files from delimited text files.

But luckily, the `readcsv()` and `readdlm()` functions have an [optional argument](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=readdlm#Base.readdlm) to help in these situations.

You should try `readcsv(filename; comment_char = '/')`.

Of course, the example above assumes that you don't have any `/` characters in your first line. If you do, then you'll have to change that `/` above to something else.

Comment: Another named parameter is `comments` which is a boolean. And `readcsv(filename; comments=false)` disables comments processing (it might be even faster).

Comment: I've tried both of these solutions and they both worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I had to revisit this page to get the syntax correct. Initially I had written,    "readcsv(filename; comments=false)".    This worked at first, but then it stopped working. I came back to this page and realized it needs a semicolon, not comma:    "readcsv(filename; comments=false)".